# Getting extra space in Codeigniter like query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My code is

```
    $this->db->like('postcoderegion','Brighton And Hove');

    $query = $this->db->get('postcode');

    $result = $query->result();
```

Mysql query

```
    SELECT * FROM `postcode` WHERE  postcoderegion  LIKE '%Brighton And  Hove%' ESCAPE '!'
```

When i see mysql query then i got an extra space between 'AND' or 'Hove'. Please let me know how can i remove this extra space. when i not set Hove then it not produced any space.

Comment: that will not be an problem

Comment: Which version of CI do you use?

Comment: Codeigniter automatically added a space in between 'AND' or 'Hove' . so it does not match to any records

Comment: `$val='Brighton And Hove'` then use `$this->db->like('postcoderegion',$val);` and check

Comment: @Saty i have alreay check like you $val='Brighton And Hove' then $this->db->like('postcoderegion',$val); bt still taking a extra space

Comment: use `this->db->escape_like_str` and check

Comment: @Saty  also tried bt still not solved  :  this->db->escape_like_str

Comment: @ksimka CI version is  3.0.1

Comment: If you not solve this issue then why down the votes

Comment: is `Brighton and Hove` one string? OR are you trying to do two like conditions?

Comment: SHow code how you get `Brighton and Hove` this value??

Comment: 'Brighton And Hove' is a string and it is single like query.  if i use  'Brighton And' then it works bt if i use 'Brighton And Hove' then in mysql  it change to 'Brighton And  Hove'

Comment: @Saty i manually pass 'Brighton And Hove' as string

Comment: Do you use `mysql` or `mysqli` driver in CI?

Comment: @ksimka i am using mysql driver

Comment: Just try with `$val='Brighton And Hove'` and `$this->db->select('*')->from('postcode')
->where("postcoderegion LIKE %$val%")->get();`

Comment: @Saty also tried this. if i use 'Brighton And Hove' or 'Brighton Or Hove' then it automatic add space before Hove in both case

Comment: May be it is bug from CI side!! and post this bug to CI forum and check there response!!

Comment: thanks for your efffort.i am also trying and checking its query builder library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**: it's fixed in 3.0.2 (https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4093), so please update to the latest version (3.0.5 currently).

(Below is a previous answer, not relevant.)

---

I think it's a bug in CI's query builder, so I've submitted an isuue — https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4551

See here — https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.0.5/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L2378 (it's for 3.0.5, but this part of code is the same as for 3.0.1).

You can try to fix it yourself or wait till it's fixed from CI team.

Comment: Did you even try reproducing it? - No.

Comment: @Narf yes i have update the current version to 3.05 now it solved